# Error Inputenc Char

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to do a presentation in spanish using beamer and so far my source looks like this:

[image]

But when I compile I get the following error message: !Package inputec Error:Unicode char B(U+392)(inputec)not set up for use with LaTex.
 So I don't know what's wrong. I would appreciate some help to overcome this issue.Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apparently a GREEK CAPITAL LETTER BETA sneaked in instead of LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B. While the function is called “beta”, its symbol is just a B.

Comment: okey. what shall i do?

Comment: If you prefer to have an upright B, similarly to Gamma, use `\mathrm{B}`.

Comment: You can also delete `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}`, as beamer already provides these.

Comment: The text in l. 180 is missing a surrounding frame?

Comment: Yes! So it seems

Comment: @ioana Could you please add the code instead of an image?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments